# How do I perform a multi-array lookup with multiple conditions? Trying to find missing values

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, so this is the code I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Check_Transactions7()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Transactions")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Transac Check")
    
    Dim sName As String: sName = dws.Range("D1").Value
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("C4:G" & sws.Range("I1").Value)
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = srg.Value
        
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        If Application.Evaluate("(Transactions!P:P = " & Data(i, 1) & ") *" & _
           "(Transactions!L:L = " & Data(i, 4) & ") *" & _
           "(Transactions!Q:Q = " & Data(i, 5) & ")") = 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            Data(k) = Data(i)
        End If
    Next i
    
    dws.Range("N2").Resize(k, 5).Value = Data

End Sub
```

It works well with one condition on the If statement, but when I try to recreate something akin to this formula:

```
=ISNA(MATCH(1, (Transactions!P:P = C4)*(Transactions!L:L = F4)*(Transactions!Q:Q = G4), 0))
```

It gives me a type mismatch error.

How can I tweak the If statement to make it work?

Thank you :)

EDIT: As a clarification, the type mismatch error shows up in the If statement. I have also tried doing COUNTIF, but it doesn't do the same thing as the formula I'm trying to recreate. The formula is trying to find missing values.

Comment: What's your specific code attempt that throws the Type Mismatch?

Comment: Do ` Data(i, 4)` need parenthesis as will evaluate to `=xyz` maybe needs to be a "  and then   Data(i, 4) and the same after.  Or maybe  Data(i, 4).address for the cell ref?

Comment: @BigBen The if statement throws the type mismatch erro

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Data(i,4) pretty much just returns a numeric value, which isn't a cell reference, so I don't think so? idk

Comment: I meant by reference, so transalated was `range("a1:a100")=$A$4` rather than the value in A4.  Im not sure evaluate will work with array formula.`

Comment: I think Evaluate will work with array formulae, but perhaps try COUNTIF or SUMPRODUCT?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm pretty sure evaluate works with array formulas as it pretty much just runs a normal excel formula

Comment: @SJR I tried COUNTIF before this, but it doesn't do what I need exactly. I need the if statement to check whether that exact combination of three values in the same row exists or not.

Comment: OK but your formula is checking all of column P, L and Q, should it just be one row each time?

Comment: @SJR Transactions worksheet has more than 18000 rows, so doing it row by row would make the macro run forever. That's why I'm trying to do something like the match formula I written out.

Comment: Why not put all the ranges into arrays, much faster than working with the worksheet.

Comment: You have `MATCH(0, ` so you're looking for rows without matches?  Might help to explain exactly what you want to do, since your code isn't doing it...

Comment: @TimWilliams You're right. I added an edit. The main purpose of this macro is to find missing values that dont have any matches.

Comment: You can't do this `Data(k) = Data(i)` - you'll need to loop over the columns and copy each value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not going too far from your original method...

(untested but you should get the general idea)

```vb
Sub Check_Transactions7()
    'formula template
    Const f = "MAX((Transactions!P:P =<a1>)*(Transactions!L:L =<a2>)*(Transactions!Q:Q =<a3>))"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, cws As Worksheet, dws As Worksheet
    Dim sName As String, sws As Worksheet, srg As Range, Data As Variant
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, frm, col As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Set cws = wb.Worksheets("Transactions")
    Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Transac Check")
    
    sName = dws.Range("D1").Value
    Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Set srg = sws.Range("C4:G" & sws.Range("I1").Value)
    
    Data = srg.Value
    k = 0
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
        'build the formula with cell addresses, not values, to avoid
        '  having to figure out if quotes are needed...
        frm = Replace(f, "<a1>", srg.Cells(i, 1).Address())
        frm = Replace(frm, "<a2>", srg.Cells(i, 4).Address())
        frm = Replace(frm, "<a3>", srg.Cells(i, 5).Address())
        'be sure to evaluate the formula in the correct context
        '  Application.Evaluate uses the Activesheet, which may not
        '  be the one you want.
        If sws.Evaluate(frm) = 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            For col = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
                Data(k, col) = Data(i, col)
            Next col
        End If
    Next i
    
    dws.Range("N2").Resize(k, 5).Value = Data

End Sub
```